# Pass String Variable Into Nework Credential Constructor for Password Arguement

Tags: c#, authentication, ldap, environment-variables, networkcredentials

What I have is a function that allows a domain user to be authenticated against their LDAP credentials. However, it works long as I hard-code a known password as a raw string... which is a no-no, of course. I wish to pass in a string value received from a `TextBox` I have set up. Here is the function:

```
public static bool fnValLDAPCreds()
    {
        bool validation;                                 

        try
        {                

            LdapConnection ADConn = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier((string)null, false, false));
            NetworkCredential NetCred = new NetworkCredential(Environment.UserName, "Password123",  Environment.UserDomainName);

            ADConn.Credential = NetCred;
            ADConn.AuthType = AuthType.Negotiate;
            // the user's authenticated here; creds used to login on the domain controller.

            ADConn.Bind(NetCred);
            validation = true;
            MessageBox.Show("You were successfully authenticated against AD using LDAP!");
        }

        catch (LdapException)
        {
            validation = false;
            MessageBox.Show("Your login was unsuccesful. Try a different set of credentials.");
        }

        return validation;
    }
```

What I've tried to do was substitute in a value from my `TextBox`, but since it lies in the `static bool` I have not been successful with making any external references to a control in the current context. I'm calling this function in button handler to fire it off. How can I swap in a `string DomPassWord` variable that gets its value from the textbox I have setup to obtain it?

`NetworkCredential NetCred = new NetworkCredential(Environment.UserName, DomPassWord,  Environment.UserDomainName);` is what I'm striving for, as I can securely match a password in the domain with no hard-coding, using something like `DomPassWord = txtUserPW.Text`. Tried the `SecureString` route, but was unsuccessful in that regard as well. Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you add a `string password` argument to the fnValLDAPCreds method, replace `"Password123"` by `password`, and call it like `fnValLDAPCreds(myTextBox.Text)` ? Or your question is not very clear

Comment: I'm having trouble visualizing the larger picture.  Are you doing this to make sure the user that's logged in as 'bob' is actually bob, by making him retype his password?  Or are you using it as an argument elsewhere to complete a credential?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot access text boxes inside a static method, since they aren't static fields (at least it looks like it from what you've written).

But you can simply pass your arguments to your method. Change it to something like this:

```
public void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    // bool valid = fnValLDAPCreds(Environment.UserName, "Password123", Environment.UserDomainName);
    bool valid = fnValLDAPCreds(txtUserName.Text, txtUserPW.Text, Environment.UserDomainName);
}

public static bool fnValLDAPCreds(string username, string password, string domain)
{
    try
    {
        LdapConnection ADConn = new LdapConnection(new LdapDirectoryIdentifier((string)null, false, false));
        NetworkCredential NetCred = new NetworkCredential(username, password,  domain);

        ADConn.Credential = NetCred;
        ADConn.AuthType = AuthType.Negotiate;
        // the user's authenticated here; creds used to login on the domain controller.

        ADConn.Bind(NetCred);
        MessageBox.Show("You were successfully authenticated against AD using LDAP!");
        return true;
    }
    catch (LdapException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Your login was unsuccesful. Try a different set of credentials.");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone with good insight, and I wish I could divide the bounty, but this was spot on. The goal was as mentioned... make sure that Charlie really is "Charlie"... by Charlie being the one who knows his domain id, AND the domain password.

Comment: To further expound, what I don't want is for NTLM to pass thru the creds based a correct username. If Charlie changes to a ridiculous password string, he's gonna need to type in that string to be authenticated. I know at this point I can encrypt the password via `SecureString`, and even set `UseSystemPasswordChar` on the box, but was fuzzy on pass of string to function!

Answer (score 0):

Kinda tangential, but have you thought about AuthType.Ntlm?  If all you're doing this for is to make sure user 'Charlie' is actually Charlie by making him type in his password?  Then you're on the right track.  But if you're trying to connect in to AD using the current user credentials as a way of getting to AD itself?  Then you might want to take a look at

```
ADConn.AuthType = AuthType.Ntlm;
```

... and letting windows handle this for you (no need to have the user type in a password at all - it'll use their current windows credentials.)